# Calculating proportion of values using condition and grouping by ID in R

Tags: r, list, sum, data.table, grouping

I have a data table:

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), score=c(78, 93, 88, 50, 101, 95, 89, 90))

# DT output
ID, score
1, 78
1, 93
1, 88
1, 50
2, 100
2, 95
2, 71
3, 90
3, 75
```

I want to obtain the proportion of scores above and below 80 **for each ID**. For example:

```
ID, above_80, below_80
1, 0.5, 0.5
2, 0.67, 0.33
3, 0.5, 0.5
```

I tried using the following:

```
proportion_DT <- DT[,list(above_80 = sum(score >= 80)/sum(score < 80),
                          below_80 = sum(score < 80)/sum(score >= 80)), by=ID]
```

But this isn't producing the correct table. Is this possible to do using `data.table`?

Comment: You must divide by the number of rows for each ID, not by the opposite proportion. Otherwise the values aren't correct

Answer (score 2):

Proportion can be calculated with `mean` of logical values. Try -

```
library(data.table)

DT[, .(above_80 = mean(score >= 80),below_80 = mean(score < 80)), ID]

#   ID above_80 below_80
#1:  1    0.500    0.500
#2:  2    0.667    0.333
#3:  3    0.500    0.500
```

---

Logical values (`TRUE` and `FALSE`) are treated as 1 and 0 respectively when we perform mathematical calculations on them.

These few examples would help clarify -

```
mean(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
#[1] 0.5

mean(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
#[1] 0.75

mean(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
#[1] 1
```

`score >= 80` similarly returns logical values and taking `mean` over them gives us the proportions for them.

**data**

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), 
                 score=c(78, 93, 88, 50, 100, 95, 71, 90, 75))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is it possible to ignore `NA` values in the column `score` when calculating the proportion? such as `mean(score >= 80, na.rm = FALSE)`

Comment: To ignore `NA` values use `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: Can you explain why `mean()` works here? My understanding is that mean(score >= 80) will simply calculate the mean of all the scores above 80?

Comment: `score >= 80` will just give `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. To get mean of all scores above 80 you would need `mean(score[score >= 80])`. Maybe the updated answer will help you understand how it works here.